# Building Crossfilter Dimension / Grouping for summarizing data

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have the following dataset:

```
    let data = [
        {patientId: 100, site: "AAA", timepoint: 0},
        {patientId: 100, site: "AAA", timepoint: 2},
        {patientId: 100, site: "AAA", timepoint: 4},
        {patientId: 100, site: "AAA", timepoint: 6},
        {patientId: 100, site: "AAA", timepoint: 8},
        {patientId: 100, site: "AAA", timepoint: 12},
        {patientId: 101, site: "AAA", timepoint: 0},
        {patientId: 101, site: "AAA", timepoint: 2},
        {patientId: 101, site: "AAA", timepoint: 4},
        {patientId: 200, site: "BBB", timepoint: 2},
        {patientId: 200, site: "BBB", timepoint: 4},
        {patientId: 200, site: "BBB", timepoint: 6},
        {patientId: 201, site: "BBB", timepoint: 0},
        {patientId: 201, site: "BBB", timepoint: 6},
        {patientId: 201, site: "BBB", timepoint: 8},
        {patientId: 201, site: "BBB", timepoint: 12},
        {patientId: 202, site: "BBB", timepoint: 0},
        {patientId: 202, site: "BBB", timepoint: 2},
        {patientId: 202, site: "BBB", timepoint: 4},
        {patientId: 202, site: "BBB", timepoint: 6},
        {patientId: 202, site: "BBB", timepoint: 8},
        {patientId: 202, site: "BBB", timepoint: 12}
    ];
```

I would like to build a pie chart the reflects the number of patients that have a given number of timepoints.  Thus the resulting pie chart based on the above data would be:

- 3 Timepoints - 2 (Patient 101 & Patient 6)
- 4 Timepoints - 1 (Patient 201)
- 6 Timepoints - 2 (Patient 100 & Patient 202)

I would like this dimension/group to work with the other basic dimensions/groups defined for the crossfilter data.

Comment: **One solution** would be before adding the data to crossfilter I could process the data and add an additional element to each row tpCount that represents the number of timepoints a patient has and then build my dimension from tpCount and build the group().reduce() based on patientId.  I was just hoping there might be a magic way without having to add the additional element to the data.

Comment: I think this is the kind of thing you'll have to do with post-processing. Build a group that calculates the number of timepoints for each patient, then iterate over that group to determine how many patients belong to each timepoint.